# Select Item in ListView Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have this to show all records from database to listview

```
   private void populatelistview()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
        {
            myDatabaseConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee", myDatabaseConnection))
            {
                SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataReader dr = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { dr["EmpID"].ToString(), dr["Lname"].ToString(), dr["Fname"].ToString() }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For example I have this result:

```
EmpID  |  Lname  |  Fname
40001  |  Smith  |  John
40002  |  Jones  |  David
40003  |  Bryan  |  Kobe
```

How I will programmatically select an item from the list above? For example I type 40002 in the textBox then this will be selected `40002  |  Jones  |  David`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle the `TextChanged` event of your `TextBox`:

```
//TextChanged event handler for your textBox1
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ListViewItem item = listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>()
                                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.Equals(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (item != null){
            listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
            item.Selected = item.Focused = true;
            listView1.Focus();//Focus to see it in action because SelectedItem won't look like selected if the listView is not focused.
        }
}
```

You can also use `ListView.FindItemWithText` method, but notice that **it matches the exact string which starts the item text**, that means you have to handle the case-sensivity yourself in case you want.

Comment: Thank you King :) What will I change when I want to find it by Lname?

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski what do you mean by `Lname`? If you mean `Name`, you can replace the `x.Text` with `x.Name`.

Comment: the code you gave is finds with EmpID, what will I change to find by Lname? What i mean with Lname is the second column on my example

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski `Lname` is the second column, so you can replace `x.Text` with `x.SubItems[1].Text`

Comment: If the second column is x.SubItems[1].Text, why in empID is `x.Text` not `x.SubItems[0].Text` ?

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski the `x` and the `x.SubItems[0]` has the same `Text`. The actual subitem starts from the index `1`.