# Programmatically focus/highlight a ListView column header in WinForms VB.NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

On a WinForms ListView, hovering over a column header causes it to focus or *highlight*. For example:

[image: Focused Header Column]

I need to do this dynamically, as in my program using the left and right keys switches the focused column.

Despite searching extensively through the properties of:

```
ListView.Columns(i)
ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection
```

I have not been able to find the property that specifically deals with column header focusing.

Would anyone be able to point to where it might be? Thank you!

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685986/select-item-in-listview-programmatically

Comment: Unrelated.. @MuratGüzel