# Is it possible to highlight a specific column header of a winforms listview?

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

Something like this:
[image]

I find some topics about highlighting cells or columns, or even all column headers but I need to highlight only a single column header to indicate the sorting to the user.

Related but no answer:
[Programmatically focus/highlight a ListView column header in WinForms VB.NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300278/programmatically-focus-highlight-a-listview-column-header-in-winforms-vb-net-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `ListView.OwenerDraw = true` and then handle `DrawItem`, `DrawSubItem` and `DrawHeader` like this:

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, 
    DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStyleRenderer renderer;
    if (e.Bounds.Contains(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
            renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Header.Item.Pressed);
        else
            renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Header.Item.Hot);
    else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) /* YOUR CRITERIA FOR SELECTED COLUMN*/
        renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Header.Item.Pressed);
    else
        renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Header.Item.Normal);
    renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, e.Bounds);
    var d = 3;
    var r = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + d, e.Bounds.Y + d,
        e.Bounds.Width - d, e.Bounds.Height - d);
    if (e.Header.ImageList != null && e.Header.ImageIndex > -1)
    {
        e.Header.ImageList.Draw(e.Graphics, r.Location, e.Header.ImageIndex);
        r.X += e.Header.ImageList.ImageSize.Width + d - 2;
        r.Width -= (e.Header.ImageList.ImageSize.Width + d - 2);
    }
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Header.Text, e.Font,
        r, e.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left);
}
private void listView1_OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
private void OnDrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

[image]

To support hot-tracking of the columns, use the following derived `ListView`:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    HeaderControl headerControl;
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (headerControl != null)
            headerControl.ReleaseHandle();
        headerControl = new HeaderControl(this);
    }
    private class HeaderControl : NativeWindow
    {
        const int LVM_GETHEADER = 0x1000 + 31;
        const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        const int WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool InvalidateRect(IntPtr hWnd, 
            IntPtr lpRect, bool erase);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, 
            int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        ListView listview;
        void Invalidate()
        {
            InvalidateRect(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, true);
        }
        public HeaderControl(ListView listview)
        {
            this.listview = listview;
            var handle = SendMessage(listview.Handle, 
                LVM_GETHEADER, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            this.AssignHandle(handle);
            listview.HandleDestroyed += (sender, e) => this.ReleaseHandle();
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE ||
                m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN ||
                m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP ||
                m.Msg == WM_MOUSELEAVE)
            {
                this.Invalidate();
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The highlight depends to the OS (and theme).

Comment: Thanks it works but the text of the columns are misaligned or rather a different font is used. Do you know any way to fix this? Basically to preserve the exact look for the columns except the highlight.

Comment: `e.DrawText` is expected to draw default text rendering. If for any reason it doesn't fit your requirement, you can use `TextRender.DrawText`.

Comment: @JoanVenge '*to indicate the sorting to the user.*' < Why not showing the sort icon, instead of highlighting the column?

Comment: What's the sort icon?

Comment: The small `˄` glyph that you see in your screenshot on top of the column (and `˅` for descending).

Comment: Oh yes I guess I can do that, it's just the app got a bit wide so i had to reduce column size, but i could try it.

Comment: Edited the answer for a better user experience.